# What should I consider when looking at pet cremation?

Tags: death

We have been talking about what to do when one of our pets die.  We both find cremation to be a good final choice.  I did some internet searching for pet cremation and find there are a lot of options and maybe some concerns.

What should I consider when researching which crematorium to choose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are a responsible and diligent "Pet Parent" in researching what you should consider when selecting a facility to cremate your beloved pet when it passes.

Pet crematories, unlike human crematories are not regulated. I would suggest you consult the Pet Loss Professionals Alliance (PLPA) through the International Cemetery, Cremation and Funeral Association (ICCFA) for a listing of pet crematories who follow the ethical guidelines outlined by the PLPA. Here is [the link to the website](http://www.iccfa.com/node/2562/grief#faq3) and they have a list of frequently ask questions that will provide more information for you in selecting someone to care for your pet.

- Do you want the remains returned to you?
- If the remains are not returned, how are they handled and where will the final resting place be?
- Of these three possible configurations which works best for you, and what does each mean according to the facility you are considering?

  - Segregated/individual cremation
  - Communal cremation
  - Separated cremation

I encourage you to visit the facilities you are interested in, as they should have an open door policy regarding their practices.